# Return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest from Initialize method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes, asp.net-mvc-controller

I want to return BadRequest status code from Initialize method. I understand, how can I do it from any Action ( return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) ), but how to do it from Initialize? I try the following:

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

but I get

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

if I don't call

```
base.Initialize(requestContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

thats by design, you should override Initialize method and call it on the base method in order for controller to get http context.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpContext.Current like;

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); return;
```

Comment: return an empty page

Comment: If you don't want an empty page just change the status. Another interesting point, if you want to process the page and not return empty, what reason you have to not call "base.Initialize"?

Comment: I just want to return a page which returned when we call return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)